# Converting int to real in SML

Tags: sml

Newbie at SML

I have the following code that returns the absolute value of a list. I need it to be of type int list -> real list. Where do I place the statement that converts it to real while constraining this code to a single line?

```
val myabs = map(fn x => if x >= 0 then x else ~x) [1,~2, 3, ~4];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You convert an *int* to *real* using `Real.fromInt`:

```
- Real.fromInt 42;
> val it = 42.0 : real
```

You can convert an *int list* into a *real list* by `List.map Real.fromInt`:

```
- List.map Real.fromInt [1, 2, 3];
> val it = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] : real list
```

You can convert an integer to its absolute using `Int.abs`:

```
- Int.abs ~42;
> val it = 42 : int
```

You can combine those two functions and so both convert an integer to its absolute and convert it to *real*:

```
- (Real.fromInt o Int.abs) ~42;
> val it = 42.0 : real
```

And you can do this for an entire list using `List.map (Real.fromInt o Int.abs)`:

```
- List.map (Real.fromInt o Int.abs) [~1, ~2, ~3];
> val it = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] : real list
```

You can express that as a single function:

```
fun myabs xs = List.map (fn x => Real.fromInt (Int.abs x)) xs
```

And you can shorten this function a bit:

```
val myabs = List.map (fn x => Real.fromInt (Int.abs x))
val myabs = List.map (fn x => (Real.fromInt o Int.abs) x)
val myabs = List.map (Real.fromInt o Int.abs)
```

So the only missing pieces were:

- Instead of `if x >= 0 then x else ~x`, use `Int.abs x`.
- To convert `x` to real, use `Real.fromInt x`.
- To apply multiple functions in sequence, `f (g x)` or `(f o g) x`, like math.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might see this, we can simply write:

```
val myabs = map(fn x => if x >= 0 then real x else real(~x)) [1,~2, 3, ~4];
```